# Can't show text in cairomm/gtkmm context

Tags: c++, cairo, gtkmm

I've been trying to draw text in a DrawingArea widget. My custom class inherits Gtk::DrawingArea, and I override the on_draw method. I have no problem drawing other things such as arcs or lines, but text just won't appear. Here is my method code:

```
bool SpeedDisplay::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
  const int width = 400;
  const int height = 400;

  cr->scale(width, height);
  cr->translate(1, 0.5);
  cr->set_line_width(m_line_width);

  cr->save();
  cr->set_source_rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
  cr->paint();
  cr->restore();
  cr->set_line_cap(Cairo::LINE_CAP_ROUND);
  cr->arc(0, 0, m_radius, 0.73*M_PI, 2.27*M_PI);
  cr->save();
  cr->set_source_rgba(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8);
  cr->fill_preserve();
  cr->restore();
  cr->stroke_preserve();
  cr->clip();


  [1]cr->set_line_cap(Cairo::LINE_CAP_ROUND);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++)
  {
    double inset = 0.05;

    cr->save();

    if(i % 2 != 0)
    {
      inset *= 0.8;
      cr->set_line_width(0.01);
    }

    if(i%2==0)  {
      cr->set_font_size(5);
      cr->select_font_face("Purisa", Cairo::FONT_SLANT_NORMAL, Cairo::FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
      //cr->move_to((m_radius+0.1) * cos (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)),(m_radius+0.1) * sin (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)));
      cr->move_to(20,30);
      cr->show_text("test");
      //cr->show_text(std::to_string(i*10));
      cr->stroke();
    }

    cr->move_to((m_radius - inset) * cos (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)),(m_radius - inset) * sin (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)));
    cr->line_to (m_radius * cos (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)),m_radius * sin (i * 0.75*M_PI / 10+(0.75*M_PI)));
    cr->stroke();
    cr->restore();
  }

  double needleAngle=test;

  cr->save();
  cr->set_line_cap(Cairo::LINE_CAP_ROUND);

  //Aiguille
  cr->save();
  cr->set_line_width(m_line_width / 3);
  cr->set_source_rgba(1.0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  cr->move_to(0, 0);
  cr->line_to(sin(needleAngle* 1.25*M_PI / 10+(1.25*M_PI)) * (m_radius * 0.9),-cos(needleAngle* 1.25*M_PI / 10+(1.25*M_PI)) * (m_radius * 0.9));
  cr->stroke();
  cr->restore();

  //Petit point noir central
  cr->arc(0, 0, m_line_width / 3.0, 0, 2 * M_PI);
  cr->fill();

  if(needleAngle==12)back=1;
  else if(needleAngle==0)back=0;
  if(back==0)test++;
  else test--;

  return true;
}
```

Here is my window once my program is compiled and executed. As you can see everything is drawn as expected but no visible text anywhere. The butttons are not part of the drawing area.

[image: Result]

Comment: You're drawing the text at a fixed point of (20,30) - are you certain this is inside the viewport? You're selecting the custom font "Purisa" - is that definitely the correct face name? 5 is pretty small - is that size in points? Check the actual line width. Check the foreground colour. Finally there's no error checking, so one of the calls may have failed but you wouldn't know which.

Comment: I forgot about the show_text() method and I found one that works with Pango. It works before the cr->scale() line and then no more. Any idea why ?

Comment: Based on what you described, I'm guessing the affine transform is being applied to the font geometry for the text and it's being scaled too small to see. Try increasing the font size, or doing a transform push/pop around the text calls.